# MATLAB yaxis customization for 0.8 0.9 0.99 0.999 numbers

Tags: matlab, axes

I have used the following code to generate a beautiful yaxis for my data. but unfortunately the resulted axes is ugly!.

```
yval = flipud([0.9999 0.9995 0.999 0.995 0.99 0.98 0.95 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.01 0.001].');
ystr = cellstr(num2str(yval));
set(gca,'YTick',yval);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',ystr);
grid on;
```

which leads to the following axes image:
[The result axes!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NgTX.jpg)

Comment: What exactly did you think was going to happen when you had 5 ticks between 0.99 and 1?

Comment: Perhaps you should use a semillogy plot.